# jQuery Get Random Element From a Selection Returned By $(selector)

Tags: jquery, random

If `$('.my-element')` matches multiple element, is there a quick way to get a random element out of these?

Comment: Yes, the same way you would get a random value from an array.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$.fn.random = function() {
  return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length));
}          

$(selector).random();
```

Comment: This one is better than mine.

Comment: I noticed a weird behavior. If the selector matches only 2 elements, your answer will tend to (I think) always return the first one, due to rounding down on `floor()`. Is it just me?

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper Because the possibility of selecting an element in that case is 50%-50% it may select the first or the second element several times, but it doesn't always select one specific element. http://jsfiddle.net/tnaFk/

Answer (score 2):

To get an even distribution, you can multiply random by the array count and drop the decimal with the bitwise operator.

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)]; //even odds of a, b, or c
```

Comment: ~~ seems to give the same result as Math.floor()

Comment: They have the same output, but ~~ computes faster, especially in older browsers.  Here's an article comparing them: http://rocha.la/JavaScript-bitwise-operators-in-practice

Answer (score 1):

```
var numElements = $('.my-element').length;
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*numElements);
//Select your random element
$('.my-element:nth-child(' + randomNum + ')');
```

Comment: That won't work completely because the [nth-child() selector is 1-based](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), whereas the random routine you created is 0-based. People often miss this because it's rare in programming to see something 1-based. Your routine will never select the 4th item if there were 4 items.