# random divs each setInterval

Tags: jquery

I've created a random effect that makes the divs shuffle (inside the .team1)
Now I have 4 of them, Is there a way that I can make it work with .each function or something better so I won't duplicate this code 4 times?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $('.team1 div:first').insertAfter( $('.team1 div:last') );
    }, 100);

    setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, randomNumber);

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="team1 size">
    <div class="brown"></div> 
    <div class="purple"></div> 
    <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
<div class="team2 size">
    <div class="brown"></div> 
    <div class="purple"></div> 
    <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
<div class="team3 size">    
    <div class="brown"></div> 
    <div class="purple"></div> 
    <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
<div class="team4 size">      
    <div class="brown"></div> 
    <div class="purple"></div> 
    <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.size { float:left; width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; margin:0 4px; }
.brown  { background:brown;    width:100px; height:100px;  }
 .purple { background:purple;  width:100px; height:100px;  }
.orange { background:orange;   width:100px; height:100px;  }
```

Comment: You don't need to clear the interval, just use the setInterval....

Answer (score 1):

Here I am just iterating through the amount of teams you have, starting at 1.

Then creating the interval object and using the `setTimeout` to cancel it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var intervals = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);

            var interval = setInterval(function(){
                $('.team' + i + ' div:first')
                    .insertAfter( $('.team' + i + ' div:last') );
            }, 100); 

            intervals.push({
                randomNumber: randomNumber,
                interval: interval
            });
        })(i);
    }   

    for (var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {   
        (function (intervals, i) {
            var intervalObj =  intervals[i];
            setTimeout(function(){
                clearInterval(intervalObj.interval);
            }, intervalObj.randomNumber);   
        })(intervals, i); 
    }
});
```

When I create the string with which jQuery will evalute I just pass in the iteration number.

I stored all these intervals in an array with their randomly generated cancellation times.

Then I just iterate over this array starting the `setTimeout` objects so that we clear up all the intervals.

---

If you want random start times, to increase "randomness" then you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var intervals = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        (function (i, intervals) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);
            var randomStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

            setTimeout(function () {
                var interval = setInterval(function(){
                    $('.team' + i + ' div:first')
                    .insertAfter( $('.team' + i + ' div:last') );
                }, 100); 

                //intervals.push({
                    //randomNumber: randomNumber,
                    //interval: interval
                //});

                setTimeout(function(){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }, randomNumber);

            }, randomStart);

        })(i, intervals);
    }   

});
```

The key thing to remember when working with `interval`s and `setTimeout`s is that the `callback` function will be run at some point in the future, so if you want something to happen when they have all completed then you will need the help of the async library.

Comment: After your edit : did you try this new code? It's randomizing only the last div and never stopping. http://jsfiddle.net/8s0nw02m/3/

Comment: Done it now @JeremyThille

Comment: Sorry but that's still not working... All divs have the same color and only the last one is stopping... http://jsfiddle.net/8s0nw02m/5/

Comment: Yeah just wrapped the `setTimeout` in the immediately invoked function

Comment: Man now that's working better! You deserved a +1 :) http://jsfiddle.net/8s0nw02m/6/

Comment: @JeremyThille i've add some more code to show extra randomness

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop and an immediately invoked function:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);

        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            $('.team' + i + ' div:first').insertAfter($('.team' + i + ' div:last'));
        }, 100);

        setTimeout(function(){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, randomNumber);
    })(i);
}
```

You need the immediately invoked function, to pass the correct `i` value for the `#setInterval()` method.

As for the randomization, a very simple solution is defining a new jQuery function (credits for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520117/2102532)):

```
$.fn.random = function() {
    return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length));
}
```

Then you can write this instead of the original:

```
$('.team' + i + ' div:first').insertAfter($('.team' + i + ' div').random());
```

Here is the [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8s0nw02m/7/).

Comment: All 4 divs have the same color at a given time. Doesn't look random. http://jsfiddle.net/8s0nw02m/4/ This solution has already been posted.

Comment: Yes, as I said the OP talks about randomization, but this (and his code) has none. I posted it first BTW.

Comment: hmmm, so that's just a hint, not an answer.

Comment: Indeed... except the random effect is never stopping :)

Comment: Oh, it is now. You fixed that. You deserve a +1 as well.